# Did Leta Lestrange sacrifice herself in order to protect one or even both of the Scamander brothers in The Crimes of Grindelwald?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

In order for the sacrificial protection to form, the victim must be given the option to live, but consciously chose death.

This is what Lily Potter did for Harry Potter. She was given the option to live (by Voldemort), but she consciously chose death.

In **Crimes of Grindelwald**, Gellert Grindelwald offers Leta Lestrange the option to join him and his cause instead of dying in the black fires of Protego Diabolica, but she chose to fight off Gellert Grindelwald knowing that she would die so that Theseus, Newt, and the others could escape and live.

Did Leta Lestrange sacrifice herself in order to form the sacrificial protection to protect one or even BOTH of the Scamander brothers in **The Crimes of Grindelwald**?

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of questions here to unpack

**Did she sacrifice herself *in order to form the sacrificial protection*?**

No. The magic that saves Harry is incredibly old, rare and largely unheard-of in the Wizarding World. Sufficiently so that Dumbledore has to basically piece together what the heck just happened after studying the scene extensively with his own near-unique abilities to detect and recreate magic.

It would seem highly unlikely that Leta, an indifferent Hogwarts student and a middle-ranking Ministry official would know of this magic, let alone be canny enough to use it.

**Is the protection spell *in evidence* in the sequel?**

There was no sign that the spell was working in the sequel, although we don't have proof-positive either way since Grindlewald didn't attempt to personally harm either brother, only capture them.

It remains to be seen whether a fourth film will be made in the series.